# Why am I getting a different instance of a ViewController than the one I pushed onto the navigationController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, nsmanagedobjectcontext

Why would I be getting a different instance of HistoryViewController than the one I instantiated and pushed onto the navigationController?

The different instance created doesn't have any of the properties I've set.

#### ProfileHomeViewController.m

```
HistoryViewController *historyViewController = nil;
historyViewController = [[HistoryViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HistoryViewController" bundle:nil];
// nib has identity of NSObject (I also tried HistoryViewController), and tableviewcontroller with identity HistoryViewController
historyViewController.profile = self.profile;

NSLog(@"%@ > %@", self, self.managedObjectContext);
// <ProfileHomeViewController: 0x5b34330> > <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x7918770>


historyViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
NSLog(@"%@ > %@", historyViewController, historyViewController.managedObjectContext);
// <HistoryViewController: 0x792a870> > <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x7918770>

[self.navigationController pushViewController:historyViewController animated:YES];
[historyViewController release];
```

#### HistoryViewController.h

```
@interface HistoryViewController : UITableViewController {

    NSManagedObject *profile;
    NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObject *profile;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
```

#### HistoryViewController.m

```
@implementation HistoryViewController

@synthesize profile;
@synthesize fetchedResultsController;
@synthesize managedObjectContext;


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"inside HistoryViewController %@ > profile %@", self, self.profile);
    // inside HistoryViewController <HistoryViewController: 0x7917750> > profile (null)

    NSLog(@"inside HistoryViewController %@ > managedObjectContext %@", self, self.managedObjectContext);
    // inside HistoryViewController <HistoryViewController: 0x7917750> > managedObjectContext (null)

    if(self.managedObjectContext == nil){
            NSLog(@"invalid managedObjectContext WTF");
            abort();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instance is the same, the references to the same instance are different (which is fine).

The method viewDidLoad is called ***before*** you set the variables which is why self.managedObjectContext == nil.

Either write a custom init method which take parameters history and managedobjectcontext and set them in the init. Or instead of using viewDidLoad, use viewWillAppear:animated...

Comment: Oh, it runs `viewDidLoad` as soon as I do `initWithNibName`? When I stepped through it in the debugger `viewDidLoad` didn't execute until after I called `pushViewController`. However, moving the fetchedResultsController init methods into `viewWillAppear` certainly did the trick!

Comment: From the docs, "This method is called after the view controller has loaded its associated views into memory". So yeah, the method is called sometime during the init phase.